# Mobile responsive webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

When I click on the HMburgar menu mobile button, the nav bar will open above the text, and the content of the banner will get purged down. I also need to fix the same content in the desktop view. unable to fix this issue. Please help.

```css
body {font-family: Georgia, Bold;
height: 5000px;
overflow-x: hidden;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.bg-img {
    
  /* The image used */
  height: 55vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(1);
    
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: top 50px left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
    
  /* Needed to position the navbar */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
 .custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    } 
    .border{
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    }
.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.navbar-logo{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px dashed #fff;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
 .bg-banner-txt-h1{
    top: 0px;
left: 0px !important;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
/* UI Properties */

    margin: 120px 240px;
    padding: 0px;
  
}
.heading-txt {
    text-align: left;
/*    font: normal normal bold 64px/73px;*/
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 38px;
}
.landingpage-bnnrtxt2{
    width: 100% !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    
}
.lp-bnnr-cta1{
        margin: -155px 230px;
        padding: 10px;
        
    }
.submit{
    width: 200px;
height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* UI Properties */
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #470DBE 0%, #C407C4 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 9px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
.graybtn{
    width: 200px;
height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* UI Properties */
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #fff 0%, #fff 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 9px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
.strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.shcursor{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.divborderwhite{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
.w200{
    width: 200px;
}



/*media Query Start*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
    body {font-family: Georgia, Bold;
height: 5000px;
overflow-x: hidden;}
    
     .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: rgb(255 255 255);
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px 10px;
        background-color: #517dfb;
        font-size: 1.1em;
         border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
    }
    .custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    } 
    .border{
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    }
    .custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
    .navbar-logo{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
}
  
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
    .bg-banner-txt-h1{
    top: 0px;
left: 0px !important;
width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 15px;
  
}
    .heading-txt {
    text-align: left;
/*    font: normal normal bold 64px/73px;*/
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 38px;
}
    .landingpage-bnnrtxt2{
    width: 100% !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    
}
    .lp-bnnr-cta1{
        margin: -155px 230px;
        padding: 10px;
        
    }
    .submit{
    width: 200px;
height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* UI Properties */
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #470DBE 0%, #C407C4 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 9px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
.graybtn{
    width: 200px;
height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* UI Properties */
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #fff 0%, #fff 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 9px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
.strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.shcursor{
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .divborderwhite{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
    .w200{
    width: 200px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
    body {font-family: Georgia, Bold;
height: 5000px;
overflow-x: hidden;}
      .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: rgb(255 255 255);
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px 10px;
        background-color: #517dfb;
        font-size: 1.1em;
         border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
    }
    .custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    } 
    .border{
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    }
    .custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
    .navbar-logo{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
}
  
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
    .bg-banner-txt-h1{
    top: 0px;
left: 0px !important;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
/* UI Properties */

    margin: 120px 240px;
    padding: 0px;
  
}
    .heading-txt {
    text-align: left;
/*    font: normal normal bold 64px/73px;*/
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 38px;
}
    .landingpage-bnnrtxt2{
    width: 100% !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    
}
    .lp-bnnr-cta1{
        margin: -155px 230px;
        padding: 10px;
        
    }
    .submit{
    width: 200px;
height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* UI Properties */
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #470DBE 0%, #C407C4 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 9px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
.graybtn{
    width: 200px;
height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* UI Properties */
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #fff 0%, #fff 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 9px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
.strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.shcursor{
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .divborderwhite{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
    .w200{
    width: 200px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    body {font-family: Georgia, Bold;
height: 5000px;
overflow-x: hidden;}
    .bg-img {
    
  /* The image used */
  height: 55vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(1);
    
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: top 50px right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
    
  /* Needed to position the navbar */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
      .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: rgb(255 255 255);
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px 10px;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-size: 1.1em;
         border-bottom: 0px dashed #fff;
    }
    .custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    } 
    .border{
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    }
    .custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
    .navbar-logo{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
}
    
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
    .bg-banner-txt-h1{
    top: 0px;
left: 0px !important;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
/* UI Properties */

    margin: 120px 240px;
    padding: 0px;
  
}
    .heading-txt {
    text-align: left;
/*    font: normal normal bold 64px/73px;*/
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 38px;
}
    .landingpage-bnnrtxt2{
    width: 100% !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    
}
    .lp-bnnr-cta1{
        margin: -155px 230px;
        padding: 10px;
        
    }
    .submit{
    width: 200px;
height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* UI Properties */
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #470DBE 0%, #C407C4 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 9px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
.graybtn{
    width: 200px;
height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* UI Properties */
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #fff 0%, #fff 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
border-radius: 9px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
.strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.shcursor{
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .divborderwhite{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
    
    .w200{
    width: 200px;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Swastik Plastics</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        </head>
<body>
    <img class="bg-img" src="https://swastikplastics.in/img/banner2.png">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-sm navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
      <div class="container">


      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" class="navbar-logo" alt="Swastik Plastics"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
               <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About Us <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="product.html">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="industries.html">Industries</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="suppliers.html">Suppliers</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
    </nav>
     <div id="" class="carousel slide">
      
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="">
          <div class="bg-banner-txt-h1">
                <div class="heading-txt fm30 strong">Grow your business <p class="">with our Polymers</p>
                    <div class="divborderwhite w200"></div>
              </div>
                <div class="landingpage-bnnrtxt2">With an experience of over 45 + years we are a trusted name in polymer trade. We take pride in our strength of network to deliver reliable, timely, and high quality polymer solutions.</div>
              
              
                
              </div>
            

          </div>
          
            <div class="col-12 ht30"></div>
         <div class="col-12 lp-bnnr-cta1" style="">
                <button class="btn submit shcursor" onclick="window.open('contactus.html','','_self')"
                  title="Click Contact Now to know more">Contact Now</button>
                <button class="btn graybtn shcursor" onclick="window.open('product.html','','_self')"
                  title="Click to Explore">Explore</button></div>
          <div class="left-bnnr-circle-btm"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code is more of where I am working on this. the only issue is the menu bar where it is unable to get what else I need to do.